# New non-table field in Zend_Db_Table_Row

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Say i am fetching a single row by using

```
$row=$model_produc->fetchRow();
```

it contains category_id but not category_name, i will fetch category name from the category table.

My Question is that how can i add new attribute in $row say $row->category_name ????
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new object, copying values from $row and adding your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but No, i would prefer to do something with the original object.